# converting html website to simple PHP templated site

Tags: php, templates, templating

I've got a simple website of a friend.  It is setup with 15 or so html pages which follow the same template. I've been asked to take a look at it and change a thing or two. The work is easy if it were not for it being duplicated so heavily.

What is a good templating engine for PHP that I could use to make it so that I only need to make layout changes in one file instead of ~15?

I suppose all I really need to do is define a single function, where the function contains the template code, and the caller specifies the inner html to use...  But I suppose there may be a better tool for this in the PHP world that I am unaware of.

Comment: By using a template engine like `Smarty` you need a little learning curve about the template engine. First try to identify if and where your site can be modularized (header,footer,left-col,right-col). Put all layout info into a `css`. Refractor the HTML code in a way you can easy manage it by simple `include` statement. Maybe you can achieve your goal without using the extra overhead of a template engine. My 2cent

Answer (score 3):

You may lookup  [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). This is one option of a very stable templating engine which is pretty long in the wild. Another thing would be to take something more recent like  [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/).

Comment: Those moutaches are calling me. /:{

Answer (score 1):

For a simple web site of a dozen of pages just create a couple of PHP files with common parts. E.g. header.php and footer.php and then include these files in all your static pages. They'll look like

```
<? include "header.php"; ?>
Actual content goes here ....
<? include "footer.php"; ?>
```

It's a common approach.
Actually, footer.php and header.php may be complex and include other .php files (e.g. top_menu.php, news.php, secondary_menu.php, and so on)

In your case a kind of CMS or a framework would be an overhead.